# Difference between class foo , class foo() and class foo(object)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I noticed all 3 -> `class foo`, `class foo()` and `class foo(object)` can be used but i am confused as to what is the difference between these 3, if there is any? (I mean in properties mainly, `python3`)

Comment: All three are the same here.

Comment: On Python 2, the first two forms do bad things. On Python 3, they're identical (unless you did something stupid to `object`).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Let's break them down:

1. `class foo`:

   - *Python 3*: It's usually the way to go. By default, Python adds `object` as the base class for you.
   - *Python 2*: It creates an old style `classobj` that will cause you all sorts of headaches.
2. `class foo()`:

   - *Python 3* and *Python 2*: Similar to `class foo` for both Python versions, trim it off, it looks ugly and makes no difference.
3. `class foo(object)`:

   - *Python 3* and *Python 2*: In both Pythons, results in a new style class that has all the goodies most know. People usually use this form when writing code that might be used in Python `2` too, explicitly inheriting from object causes the class to be new style in Python 2 and makes no difference in 3 (apart from some extra typing).

Comment: Also see [my answer on a duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58015137/2464597) for some (I think) illustrative examples of the above.