# What's the difference between declaring `class A` and `class A()`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

We define class in python as following:

```
class A:
    def x(self):
        print("In x")
```

But i just made a typo and it executed successfully in linux cli with python version 3.7. Here it is:

```
class A():
    def x(self):
        print("In x")
```

What does this mean???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can optionally [inherit from other classes](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inheritance-in-python/) with the syntax `class Child(Parent):` in Python. Leaving no argument in the parenthesis is the same as leaving the parenthesis off: you just inherit from the base `object` class and nothing else. For example:

```
class A:
    pass

class B(object):
    pass

class C():
    pass

import inspect

inspect.getmro(A)
# (__main__.A, object)
inspect.getmro(B)
# (__main__.B, object)
inspect.getmro(C)
# (__main__.C, object)
```

All equivalent. As a counter-example:

```
class D(A):  # inherit from A
    pass

inspect.getmro(D)  # should include A now
# (__main__.D, __main__.A, object)
```

Answer (score 1):

in python 2.x there would be a difference, but in python3 it is the same.

the long version
class A(object):
    pass

is the same as
class A():
    pass

since object is the default input of a class

this one is just an even shorter version of the one above
class A:
    pass